# Widget which calls JavaScript

Tags: javascript, yii, widget

I create for my project a year/month enter widget in Yii.

(It is planned to be implemented as two `<select>` tags, one for a year and one for a month. I plan to reboot the page on every change (be it year change or month change). But that are unimportant details.)

I may pass 'onchange' attribute with some JavaScript to the widget in my PHP code.

Now to the question: This JavaScript should have access to the values `year` and `month`. How to pass these values to JavaScript code in an implementation agnostic way? (I mean that for example I may change the year input field to be a text input instead of a `<select>` or whatever changes we may wish). This change should not change the way `year` and `month` are passed to JavaScript.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyword 'this' in JavaScript for that purpose. So try that (need JQuery):

```
<select onchange="func(this)">
    <!--options here-->
</select>

<input onchange="func(this)">

<script>
function func(obj) {
    var value = $(obj).val();
    // logic..
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing some JavaScript code as `onchange` attribute, I may pass a two-argument (year, month) JavaScript function as some other attribute.

Is it the best solution?